# How is the best way GWT client load data from server file

Tags: gwt

my GWT client needs to load data from a file located in the server exactly under war directory what is the best solution???.
The data are double values.
I know the client at the end is converted to java script.

Comment: You app should make a call to the server, and a server will return the contents of this file. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: could you explain more I mean can the server the date as a file???

Comment: If it is so static, as you claim in the comment, does it mean, it will only change on compile-time?

If so, why not simply place it's contents in a class with a `static double[]` array? No need to transfer it at all.

You could also `<jsp:include>` the file and read the contents into a JSON object, that you read via JSNI in your GWT code.
That way, the file will be loaded together with your host page. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to read the data from file!! is it so?
if it is true, you have to create servlet to read data from file. Then make a request to servlet from client. Let say example
1) ReadFileServlet.java: This is server side code that contains code to read file from location.
2) ReadFileGWT.java: This is gwt file. From here, you make request to call ReadFileServlet file.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: what about  ClientBundle and DataResource the data file I use is static and will never changed?? the problem is how to access these data???

Comment: I am not getting what u want. as ClientBundle and dataresource is to make url strongly cachable. Through `@source` annotation, u can use the data throgh builder api. more details http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html